# Son statut de/du sauveur du peuple polonais

Tags: prépositions

> Il était alors l’heure de remettre en cause son statut **de** sauveur du
> peuple polonais.

Pourquoi a-t-il été écrit : « statut de sauveur »  ? On a précisé qu'il s'agissait du sauveur du peuple polonais, d'un sauveur en particulier.

Ne devrait-on pas dire :

> Il était alors l’heure de remettre en cause son statut **du** sauveur du
> peuple polonais.

?

Answer (score 2):

Parce que il s'agit de *son* statut, donc on a déjà précisé de qui le statut est: c'est le sien. On ne peut pas préciser de qui est le statut deux fois dans la même phrase.

Il existe une nuance entre l'utilisation des mots "de" et "du":

On dit par exemple:

> **Il faudrait redéfinir le statut du président.**
>
> (pour parler du statut de ce rôle de président, sans nécessairement considérer à quel individu en particulier le statut s'applique.)

Mais on dit:

> **Jean est fier de son statut de président.**
>
> (pour parler du statut de Jean en particulier, Jean étant le président.)

De même, on ne peut pas dire "son t-shirt du garçon". On peut dire:

> **le t-shirt du garçon**
>
> (pour parler d'un t-shirt qui appartient au garçon.)

Ou bien on peut dire dit:

> **son t-shirt de garçon**
>
> (pour parler d'un t-shirt conçu pour les garçons, qui appartient à quelqu'un qui n'est pas forcément un garçon.)

Comment: J'aimerais souligner que ces deux explications s'excluent. 
Dans le premier exemple "du" est utilisé pour parler en généralisant, dans le seconde vous avez mis "de".

Answer (score 0):

Par simplification, on admettra que le syntagme nominal *son statut du sauveur* est incorrect puis que la préposition *de* introduit l'attribut du complément d'objet *sauveur du peuple polonais*.